# How to use autowired components with spring boot websocket?

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-websocket

I have spring boot app.
Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    TestComponent testComponent;

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        testComponent.test();
    }
}
```

Also I have another class here:

```
@Component
public class TestComponent {

    public void test(){
        System.out.println("lalala");
    }
}
```

Here are my dependencies from the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit', version: '2.33'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.1-jre'
}
```

Also here is my main spring boot file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({FileStorageProperties.class})
@EnableWebSocket
public class MyAppApplication implements WebSocketConfigurer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/socket1").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

On websocket message handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) is called but the autowired components are null.
I checked if I create some new method in WebSocketHandler and anotate it with @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) on application start the testComponent is available but it is still not available when handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) is called from the websocket. There is something wrong with the websocket call !
Is there anybody with the same problem?

Comment: Are your classes componentscanned well? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Comment: they are all in one directory. They must be scanned well. Also the same class (TestComponent) can be used with autowire in another class but exactly in WebSocketHandler it is null when I call the handleTextMessage() on message from the websocket. I think there is something wrong with the websocket. I tried to add @ComponentScan("org.springframework.web.socket.handler") in the main spring boot class (org.springframework.web.socket.handler is the package of AbstractWebSocketHandler) but then handleTextMessage() is not called on websocket message. So strange ..........

Comment: Please, add this code to the WebSocketHandler:

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("Constructed!");
    }

And tell me if the print is being reached.

Comment: Hi @dimilalabar I am having the exact same problem... Did you get it sorted? Please share with me.

Comment: Hi @HugoSartori i have the exact same problem....and i tried your code...it worked....what else could be the issue